Subfactors with integer Jones index
Is there any integer (Jones) index subfactor which is not extremal?

The $A_{\infty}^{(1)}$ subfactors, introduced by Vaughan Jones in his paper, realize every index $\ge 4$, and are non-extremal. See Remark 6.6 in this paper by Das-Ghosh-Gupta. See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/207806/34538

Thank you very much.

@SebastienPalcoux Any other examples?

I guess you can get infinitely many examples by tensor product. To avoid such straightforward construction, we can request maximality. Eveything is explained in https://mathoverflow.net/q/207806/34538

I meant other type of examples. Note that commuting square subfactors will always be extremal.
